# Decompressing GZip in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm having a hard time figuring this out. Here's what I'm trying:

```
ghci> :m +System.FileArchive.GZip  -- From the "MissingH" package
ghci> fmap decompress $ readFile "test.html.gz"
*** Exception: test.html.gz: hGetContents: invalid argument (invalid byte sequence)
```

Why am I getting that exception?

I also tried `Codec.Compression.GZip.decompress` from the [zlib package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/zlib-0.5.3.3), but I can't get the types to work out to `String` instead of `ByteString`.

Comment: This is not a complete answer, but probably `readFile` is trying to decode `test.html.gz` as if it were text encoded in your system encoding. Use a binary read instead.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The conversion from `ByteString` to `String` depends on the character encoding of the compressed file, but assuming it's ASCII or Latin-1, this should work:

```
import Codec.Compression.GZip (decompress)
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as LBS
import Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 (unpack)

readGZipFile :: FilePath -> IO String
readGZipFile path = fmap (unpack . decompress) $ LBS.readFile path
```

If you need to work with some other encoding like UTF-8, replace `unpack` with an appropriate decoding function, e.g. [`Data.ByteString.Lazy.UTF8.toString`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/utf8-string/latest/doc/html/Data-ByteString-Lazy-UTF8.html#v%3atoString).

Of course, if the file you're decompressing isn't a text file, it's better to keep it as a `ByteString`.